# JRE crash - A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: memory-leaks, crash, stack-trace, java

I am using an open source JAVA based crawler which juggles millions of URI objects between the memory and disk. Basically the program is memory intensive.
The crash occurs once in a blue moon, I haven't been able to find the reason.

Pasting a part of the error-log, any pointers what possibly is causing this?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b97ee1a07df, pid=1445, tid=1102055744
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6227df]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000059db5000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000041a00000,0x0000000041b01000] [id=1460]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000000000d5

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000008, RBX=0x0000000059df95f8, RCX=0x0000000000000005, RDX=0x00002aabee55cec0
RSP=0x0000000041affb60, RBP=0x0000000041affbd0, RSI=0x0000000059df95f0, RDI=0x00002aaab5c758b8
R8 =0x000000000000004b, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x00002aaaafbdfb01, R11=0x00002aabe4c0df38
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x00002aabee55cec0, R14=0x00002aabe4c0e068, R15=0x0000000059df95f0
RIP=0x00002b97ee1a07df, EFL=0x0000000000010297, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000041affb60)
0x0000000041affb60:   0000000000000400 0000000059d9bfa0
0x0000000041affb70:   0000000000000005 01002aaab6b05998
0x0000000041affb80:   0000000041affbb0 0000000000000009
.
0x0000000041affd40:   0000000059db5810 0000000059db5820
0x0000000041affd50:   0000000059db5bf8 0000000041affd80 

Instructions: (pc=0x00002b97ee1a07df)
0x00002b97ee1a07cf:   41 5e 41 5f c9 c3 48 8b 4a 10 4c 89 fe 4c 89 ea
0x00002b97ee1a07df:   ff 91 d0 00 00 00 eb dc 49 8b 55 08 eb c9 4c 89 

Stack: [0x0000000041a00000,0x0000000041b01000],  sp=0x0000000041affb60,  free space=3fe0000000000000018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x6227df]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6230b0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6222d4]
V  [libjvm.so+0x23d872]
V  [libjvm.so+0x62583b]
V  [libjvm.so+0x365dda]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5da2af]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00002aac4c093800 JavaThread "JEEvictor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24783, stack(0x0000000046504000,0x0000000046605000)]
  0x000000005a3a2000 JavaThread "JEEvictor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24782, stack(0x0000000046605000,0x0000000046706000)]
  0x00002aac4c093000 JavaThread "JEEvictor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24781, stack(0x0000000046b0a000,0x0000000046c0b000)]
Other Threads:
  0x0000000059dfb000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000041c02000,0x0000000041d03000] [id=1462]
  0x0000000059e32800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000423c3000,0x00000000424c4000] [id=1469]

=>0x0000000059db5000 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000041a00000,0x0000000041b01000] [id=1460]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000000059d8b860] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000059dfb000
[0x0000000059d8bd60] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00002aac3c2dd000

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 835840K, used 825021K [0x00002aabb3600000, 0x00002aabeffc0000, 0x00002aac33600000)
  eden space 809024K, 100% used [0x00002aabb3600000,0x00002aabe4c10000,0x00002aabe4c10000)
  from space 26816K, 59% used [0x00002aabe4c10000,0x00002aabe5baf538,0x00002aabe6640000)
  to   space 27136K, 6% used [0x00002aabee540000,0x00002aabee6ec138,0x00002aabeffc0000)
 PSOldGen        total 4096448K, used 3687089K [0x00002aaab3600000, 0x00002aabad670000, 0x00002aabb3600000)
  object space 4096448K, 90% used [0x00002aaab3600000,0x00002aab946ac6b0,0x00002aabad670000)
 PSPermGen       total 44608K, used 44199K [0x00002aaaae200000, 0x00002aaab0d90000, 0x00002aaab3600000)
  object space 44608K, 99% used [0x00002aaaae200000,0x00002aaab0d29ec0,0x00002aaab0d90000)

Dynamic libraries:
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1116699                            /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 1116699                            /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/java
40384000-40387000 ---p 40384000 00:00 0 
40387000-40485000 rwxp 40387000 00:00 0 
40647000-4064a000 ---p 40647000 00:00 0 
4064a000-40748000 rwxp 4064a000 00:00 0 
 2aac4cb1b000-2aac50000000 ---p 2aac4cb1b000 00:00 0 
2b97eda60000-2b97eda61000 rwxp 2b97eda60000 00:00 0 
2b97eda71000-2b97eda72000 rwxp 2b97eda71000 00:00 0 
2b97eda72000-2b97eda79000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1119007                    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
2b97eda79000-2b97edb7a000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 1119007                    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
2b97edb7a000-2b97edb7c000 rwxp 00008000 fd:00 1119007                    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
2b97edb7c000-2b97edb7e000 rwxp 2b97edb7c000 00:00 0 
2b97edb7e000-2b97ee332000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1119054                    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b97ee332000-2b97ee432000 ---p 007b4000 fd:00 1119054                    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b97ee432000-2b97ee5bc000 rwxp 007b4000 fd:00 1119054                    /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b97ee5bc000-2b97ee5f5000 rwxp 2b97ee5bc000 00:00 0 
7fffc4df8000-7fffc4e0e000 rwxp 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dheritrix.home=/heritrix/heritrix-3.1.0 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.archive.net -Dheritrix.out=/heritrix/heritrix-3.1.0/heritrix_out.log -Xmx6144M 
java_command: org.archive.crawler.Heritrix -p 8544 -b / -a user:pass
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
PATH=/apps/pig-0.9.0/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin:/home/ppra/bin:/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin:/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/bash
  ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

uname:Linux 2.6.18-164.11.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 6 13:26:04 EST 2010 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 268287, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:1.31 0.80 0.67

CPU:total 16 (8 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 29 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 32960544k(162620k free), swap 6291448k(6290568k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_18-b07), built on Dec 17 2009 13:42:22 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Sat Aug  4 07:27:56 2012
elapsed time: 242358 seconds
```

Comment: Have you tried with a more recent JRE (you seem to be on 1.6.0_18)?

Comment: I am upgrading to a recent JRE but my problem is that the issue is not reproducible even when simulated on the same JRE and same program execution. And I want to know what exactly is the reason for the crash. I suspect, it's related to memory. When heap size grows bigger, something faults.

Answer (score 0):

Well, SIGSEGV denotes a segfault. Likely you are either trying to read something that wasn't ever initialized, or the garbage collector is screwing you.